# Linux’s Bash shell in Windows 10 and mathematica

Tags: interoperability, windows, linux, command-line

As we know, Linux’s Bash shell is coming to Windows 10. Now, I want to know, how to using Run[] command or other commands to run some commands like gfortran installed in Linux of Win10 ?  And, is it possible to call mathematica using Bash shell in Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 5):

As we [also](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) [know](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/) [from](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) [a](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx) [number](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) of sources, bash-over-windows-10 is in beta, not yet feature complete, and it is not really meant to interface with Windows apps at the moment. If you can get a command to run from a `cmd` shell (like, [say](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/), running `bash -c "vi"`, which will hopefully launch a graphical `vi` instance) then it *should* work just fine through `Run[]`. Otherwise, you're probably asking too much from asystem that is too young at the moment. Similarly, launching a Mathematica kernel from inside bash seems unlikely to be possible anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

Installing the Windows git-bash version from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) enables a simple way to run bash under Windows 10 from Mathematica:

```
RunProcess[{"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c", 
  "bash --version | head -1 | tr -d '\n'"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

results in

```
(* "GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)" *)
```

Comment: I think it's not specifically bash that he wanted, but running native Linux programs in the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).